# What is the correct way of writing synchronous code in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

A few days ago, I watched an interesting video on YouTube about [Broken Promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV-u_Ow47s0) that [James Snell](https://github.com/jasnell) introduced.

You can find out some great examples that have introduced in the video from his [repository](https://github.com/jasnell/broken-promises).

> According to what he said, we should not wrap purely synchronous code in a promise. And if we absolutely need a function to return a promise then resolve the promise synchronously by using `Promise.resolve() method`. *Importantly, he also pointed out that run your code synchronously and save yourself the trouble of all those additional promise allocations*.

After finished watching the video, I've looked into my code. And wonder what if I've done something similar as he mentioned in the clip.

Let me show you some examples.

Here's an async function that waits for promises to be resolved.

```js
async getGameShotDetail(buffer: Buffer, fileSize: number): Promise<ShotDetail[]> {
  const { latitude, longitude, shotType } = await somefunc()
  const data = await Promise.all([
    this.parseHoleNumber(shotType),
    this.parseShotType(shotType),
    this.parseCoordinate(this.sliceBufferIntoPieces(latitude)),
    this.parseCoordinate(this.sliceBufferIntoPieces(longitude)),
  ]);

  return some async func(data);
}
```

The first two methods `parseHoleNumber` and `parseShotType` inside an array of `Promise.all()` method does pretty much the same thing. It reads data from a binary file and they both eventually return an array of numbers as a promise.

```js
private parseHoleNumber(buffer: number[]): Promise<number[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (buffer.length < 0) {
      reject([]);
    }
    /* tslint:disable:no-bitwise */
    resolve(buffer.filter(n => n !== 0).map(holeNumber => holeNumber >> 3));
    /* tslint:enable:no-bitwise */
  });
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to write synchronous functions that return a promise. The problem is I'm not sure about my code is well written what James Snell said.

As far as I know, all [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods, including push, are synchronous. And I'm uncertain whether pushing an item to an array from `new Promise(executor)` is safe or not.

Is there any sort of vulnerable or incorrectly use of promise from my code?

```js
private sliceBufferIntoPieces(
  buffer: number[] | string[],
  chunkSize: number = 4,
): Promise<Array<number[]>> {
  const arr = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += chunkSize) {
      arr.push(buffer.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    arr.length > 0 ? resolve(arr) : reject([]);
  });
}

private async parseCoordinate(buffer: Promise<Array<number[]>>): Promise<number[]> {
  const itemsAreZero = (item): boolean => item === 0;

  return Promise.resolve(
    (await buffer) // Maybe this is bad?
      .filter(buff => !buff.every(itemsAreZero))
      .map(byte => +(this.read4byteItem(byte) / 360000).toFixed(6)),
  );
}
```

Comment: All of your code, except your initial `await somefunc()` is synchronous, there is no need of using promises in any of those methods

Comment: Another case of *Let's use Promises because they're the latest tool* - I got a new screwdriver, let's paint the house with it

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, if the code makes you feel uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the functions in your code are doing anything asynchronous. Once the `await somefunc` line runs, everything else you're doing is synchronous, but you're still wrapping everything in a `Promise.all` call for some reason. You can fix that (and avoid the antipattern the video discusses) by removing the unnecessary Promise constructions and `Promise.resolve`s:

```
async getGameShotDetail(buffer: Buffer, fileSize: number): Promise<ShotDetail[]> {
  const { latitude, longitude, shotType } = await somefunc()
  const data = [
    this.parseHoleNumber(shotType),
    this.parseShotType(shotType),
    this.parseCoordinate(this.sliceBufferIntoPieces(latitude)),
    this.parseCoordinate(this.sliceBufferIntoPieces(longitude)),
  ];

  return some async func(data);
}
```

```
private parseHoleNumber(buffer: number[]): number[] {
    if (buffer.length < 0) {
      // If you don't want processing to continue in getGameShotDetail, throw an error:
      throw new Error('Buffer length negative??');
      // Otherwise, just return an empty array:
      // return [];
    }
    /* tslint:disable:no-bitwise */
    return buffer.filter(n => n !== 0).map(holeNumber => holeNumber >> 3);
    /* tslint:enable:no-bitwise */
}
```

```
private sliceBufferIntoPieces(
  buffer: number[] | string[],
  chunkSize: number = 4,
): Array<number[]> {
  const arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += chunkSize) {
      arr.push(buffer.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      // Same as above - do you want to return an empty array, or stop execution entirely?
      throw new Error('Buffer empty');
    }
}
```

With regards to the above two functions, if the buffers are empty, consider - do you actually want to stop execution entirely, or do you want to continue executing with an empty array? If you want to stop execution, throw an error (with `throw`) - otherwise, don't throw, and just return an empty array.

Since `sliceBufferIntoPieces` doesn't need to return a Promise, there's no need for `parseCoordinate` to wait for it to resolve either:

```
private parseCoordinate(buffer: Array<number[]>): number[] {
  const itemsAreZero = (item): boolean => item === 0;

  return buffer
      .filter(buff => !buff.every(itemsAreZero))
      .map(byte => +(this.read4byteItem(byte) / 360000).toFixed(6))
}
```

Also keep in mind that Typescript can almost always infer the type of a function's return value without you having to explicitly specify it - unless your linter is forcing you to note the return types, feel free to leave those out.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I appreciate it. Can I just remove Promise constructions from `somefunc()` too? The line `await somefunc()` is just returning objects.

Comment: If `somefunc` isn't actually doing anything asynchronous, then yes, make it synchronous.

Comment: One more thing! Do you think the current code will affect the performance of an app in the near future?

Comment: Only if the buffers were unreasonable huge, but I don't think they are

Comment: Thank you. I'm still wondering in which cases should I write my own async functions.

Comment: Use asynchronous functions and/or Promises when you need to wait for something asynchronous to resolve before doing more work - for example, when waiting for a network request to resolve, or when waiting for a `fs.readFile` to finish. Otherwise, best to stick to synchronous code.